Issue mapping file uploads to custom objects in Omniscript
I am new to Salesforce and have been mostly learning as I go. The main goal at hand is to create a scholarship application for the general public to access and fill out, then be reviewed internally by our team. I was told to use Omniscript to build the application and after addressing many issues, it seems my last one happens to be with file uploads. I have around 6 different file uploads the applicant has to submit. Some upload fields only require 1 file submission while others may need up to 4 files submitted. Of the six file uploads I have successfully mapped the first four to the custom object I have created to capture the user input. The final two file upload fields I have mapped the exact same and made sure the JSON code was structured identically to the ones that are working.
I am using a dataraptor load with contentdocumentlink objects linked to my custom object to get the files connected. I have been looking at this for days now and nothing I have done seems to be allowing the final two file uploads to successfully populate.
Additionally, I am getting the error " Required fields are missing: [ContentDocumentId]" upon the user submitting the omniscript. I am sure these are related and I even went to ensure the file uploads are not required to address this issue with no luck. Any and all advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!
